# How to migrate from aSmack to Smack

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

In my android application,

1. How can i set the the custom attributes for message tag in Smack 4.1?..I was trying to set xmlns but there is no such method. Is there any alternative?
2. Also, help me with CarbonManager class in Smack 4.1. While migrating from asmack to Smack 4.1, Carbon Manager class is showing error.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question,smack has a class named JivePropertiesManager which include a static method addProperty,you can use this to do what you want to do.

```
public static void addProperty(Stanza packet, String name, Object value) {
    JivePropertiesExtension jpe = (JivePropertiesExtension) packet.getExtension(JivePropertiesExtension.NAMESPACE);
    if (jpe == null) {
       jpe = new JivePropertiesExtension();
       packet.addExtension(jpe);
    }
    jpe.setProperty(name, value);
}
```

There method can add properties for SMACK's Stanza(Message extends it).

For your second question please post your code or more details about error.